# Conexión de Google App Scrip con HTML en local

Tags: html, google-apps-script

tengo un script que toma como parámetro un ID para buscar los datos relacionados con ese ID. Los datos se encuentran alojados en un Spreadsheet. Ejemplo del Spreadsheet:

| ID | Nombre | Carrera |

1        Oscar      CL

2         maría       matemáticas

3         patricia        medicina

Al ejecutar el script me devuelve en el buscador el resultado deseado. Ejemplo:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykJuKHDSs7pB9m2lz1hp9ugXh-nWThZ32R6Gr8gjoywfstq3jl/exec?id=1

Devuelve Oscar y CL.

Código del script:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("LINK al Sheet");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

function doGet(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  

function doPost(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  


function search(e){
 var id = e.parameter.id;

  var values_name = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var values_carrera = sheet.getRange(2,3,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  json = "";

  for (var i = 0; i<values_name.length;i++){
    if (values_name[i][0] == id){
      i = i+2;
      var name = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var carrera = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();

      if(json==""){
        json = {
          'Name':name,
          'Carrera':carrera
        }
      }
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(json)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }

  }

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Estudiante no encontrado.").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);

}
```

Mi duda es cómo llamar a esa función desde un HTML y JS (en local) y que me devuelva los valores correspondientes.

Hasta ahora he probado con esto:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <input type="number" id="ID_estudiante" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==10) return false;" class="book-now" placeholder="ID estudiante"><br />
        <button id="login" type="button" onclick="setValues()">Senden</button></body><br>
    </body>
    
    <script>
        function setValues() {
            var op_code;
            op_code = Number(document.getElementById("ID_estudiante").value);
            login(ID_estudiante);
        }
    
        function login(ID_estudiante) {
            var id = ID_estudiante;
            var script_login = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykJuKHDSs7pB9m2lz1hp9ugXh-nWThZ32R6Gr8gjoywfstq3jl/exec";
            var url = script_login + "?callback=ctrlq&" & "?id=" + id + "&action=search";
            var request = jQuery.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function() {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("error");
                },
            });
    
        }
    
        function ctrlq(e) {
            alert('Registered Successfully')
        }
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Pero la función siempre devuelve un error.

Alguna idea?

Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para llamar una secuencia de comandos (script) de Google Apps Script desde una aplicación externa, ya sea un HTML / JavaScript local, debes usar la [API de Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/). Los detalles se encuentran en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute y puedes ver un ejemplo con las instrucciones paso a paso en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/js

En términos generales los pasos son:

1. Prerequisitos

   - Contar con un servidor web
   - Contar con una cuenta de Google con los servicios de Google necesarios habilitados
2. Activar la API de Google Apps Script
3. Configurar la aplicación HTML/CSS/JavaScript
4. Ejecutar la aplicación